# Can I keyboard interrupt GridSearchCV somehow and still have the best parameters gathered until that point?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, grid-search

So I have the following code-

```
params = {'n_estimators': [1000, 2000], 'max_depth': [10, 20], 'min_samples_split': [2, 3],
          'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.05, 0.01], 'loss': ('ls', 'huber', 'lad', 'quantile'), 'verbose': [1]}
gbr = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor()
clf = GridSearchCV(gbr, params)
```

And, although I don't think I've given it much to contemplate, it's taking FOREVER to determine the best parameters. After watching for a couple hours I've seen great instances (`verbose:[1]`) and wish to stop it from continuing. I don't want to have to come back to this in the morning and hope that it's finished. I want to finish it now without losing the hours of tuning in the process.

Is there a safe way I can stop the tuning and still have the best result?

Comment: I dont think so. The best you can hope is setting the verbose to maybe 3 and then searching the output for all the scores upto the point of interrupt and then finding the best yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following approach to get optimal hyperparameters for DNN (which you can use for yourself):

- for loop for parameter #1
- inside for loop for parameter #2
- ...
- inside you fit your model and save/print results, pictures etc.

Sure, if you ctrl-c your running code your pictures, logs will no be removed.

---

But as I see here, you do not have much possible parameter combinations inside. So why it runs forever:

1. Data is extremely big (take subsample)
2. Number of cv-s is very big (take less than 10)
3. Reduce # of estimators. 1000-2000 is too much
4. Take small max_features
5. Reduce max_depth. 10-20 is too much I believe. For most cases it should be <10 (try with 3-5 for example)
6. Use XGBoost (it's a lot faster). In general, XGBoost and GBR are the same (and both tend not to overfit with a growing number of estimators) but XGBoost has some additions that helps in this better.
7. Run on some server or upgrade your PC :)

Answer (score 2):

If this question is anything to go by, [then the answer appears to be no.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377052/if-i-interrupt-sklearn-grid-search-fit-before-completion-can-i-access-the-curr)
I know when I did this a few weeks back, I too got impatient. I just ctrl+f'ed through the logs for numbers I was hoping it would achieve. Starting at 95,94,93,... etc.